# Calling php var on page inside javascript/ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have the following code for a checkbox

```
<div class="switch switch-lg switch-primary">
<input type="checkbox" name="switch" data-plugin-ios-switch checked="checked" value="usersname:1" />
</div>
```

When I change the checkbox, the following event is triggered

```js
<script>  
$('input[name="switch"]').on('change', function(){
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'page.php',
  data: {
   example: $('#example').val()
  }
 }).always(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  if (data.response == 'success') {
   // Success
  } else {
   // Error
  }
 });
});    
</script>
```

I am wondering how I get the value of "usersname:1" in my page.php? I'm guessing it's around `example: $('#example').val()`?

Basically the page.php will update a mysql database with the value 1, but specific to only that user, so i need to somehow pull up the username:1 in that script portion or the page.php but don't know how to call it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `id` attributes in your checkbox. You can't define `id` attributes in checkbox .

```
<div class="switch switch-lg switch-primary">
<input type="checkbox" id="example" name="switch" data-plugin-ios-switch checked="checked" value="usersname:1" />
</div>
```

Otherwise You can change `example: $('#example').val()` to `example: $(this).val()`

Comment: Thanks so much, this works like a charm!!!! I confirmed both options worked (adding ID or changing the example output). You finally solved two days of headache for me!!!!

Answer (score 1):

In order to send data to php your have to modify your code line:
`data: {
            example: $('#example').val()
        }`

to:

```
    data: {
        example: $('#example').val(),
        switch: $(this).val()
    }
```

The code finally becomes:

```js
$('input[name="switch"]').on('change', function(){
console.log($(this).val());
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'page.php',
  data: {
   example: $('#example').val(),
      switch: $(this).val()
  }
 }).always(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  if (data.response == 'success') {
   // Success
  } else {
   // Error
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="switch switch-lg switch-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" name="switch" data-plugin-ios-switch checked="checked" value="usersname:1" />
    </div>
```

**In PHP you can get value using $_REQUEST['switch']**

Answer (score 0):

You can get `example` value in page.php by `$_POST['example']`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a tricky one.

With `example: $('#example').val()` you will pass the VALUE of an input with ÌD `example` as a post var (so you can catch it with $_POST["example"] in the end script. Thing is, anyone can put anything into that and edit other username.

You should be doing this by calling a $_SESSION variable with the userid or something alike so people don't tamper with the data or make some XSS.

So, if you want to go with that, just put the ID example into your input and it will work (or edit it to match your fields), but i suggest to find another way.

Comment: Thanks mate! This is all taking place within a PHP session and I'll check session vars on the action page, but good thinking for others that stumble on this and don't have that setup! Thanks for your help!